# Hazelcast instances as osgi services on karaf - avoiding overhead

Tags: java, osgi, hazelcast, karaf

we use karaf and hazelcast together. The hazelcast instance has a backing database map-store and is offered as a osgi service. 
In some deployments, for 2 groups of tables, the database map-store is the same for each group but in some cases different databases are used. 
Many karafs (up to 10) are deployed with this configuration and each will have hazelcast instances.

Does it make sense to optimize the deployment so that in the case that only one backing map-store exists, only one hazelcast instance is used? Or is the 
overhead of 2 instances of hazelcast per karaf neglegible enough that this effort is not worth the trouble?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without more context. I mean, I'm sure you've measured the overhead, but you don't tell us about your application, system, constraints, etc.

Comment: Actually I thought of adding this information but was afraid it would be too much. I'll come back later with more information on the issue - it will surely need a drawing.